# Firebase emulator cloud function throws cors error when hit from frontend

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have this function that works perfectly in production however when running locally I get cors errors

```
export const listUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    const data = await getSomeUsers(10)
    res.json(data)
})
```

emulators starts fine:

[image]

cors issue:

[image]

Comment: Please don't show images of text.  Edit the question and copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Comment: I've been doing that for years, seems to me that the most important searchable stuff is already in there..

Comment: I'm asking as a favor for all the people with disabilities that find small graphical text to be difficult or impossible to read.  Also, please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: They click on the image and it gets larger plus you have the colours.

Comment: That's not the way disabilities work.  It's most helpful to simply copy the text into the question.

Comment: ok noted, thx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

[Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

> Chrome does not support localhost for CORS requests (a bug opened in
>   2010, marked WontFix in 2014).
>
> To get around this you can use a domain like lvh.me (which points at
>   127.0.0.1 just like localhost) or start chrome with the --disable-web-security flag (assuming you're just testing).

Comment: Can you tell me more about lvh.me  ?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26461727)

Comment: @bruno, isn't the essential part included in the quote?

Comment: --disable-web-security  works great thx for my issue

Comment: Chrome does support CORS from localhost, this is extremely misleading. The bug was closed because it was not reproducible.